# Why EF runs aggregation locally?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm working with weather dataset, so there are a lot of data in DBMS (MSSQL). I want to fetch latest record of specific sensors in the last 2 hours.

Data in DB can be simplified to this:

```
| Date(DateTime)      | SensorId(int) | Value(Double) |
| ------------------- | ------------- | ------------- |
| 2019-10-09T23:00:00 |       1       |       15      |
| 2019-10-10T00:00:00 |       1       |       15      |
| 2019-10-10T00:00:00 |       2       |      3.5      |
| 2019-10-10T00:00:00 |       3       |      765      |
| 2019-10-10T01:11:11 |       1       |       10      |
| 2019-10-10T01:11:11 |       2       |       4       |
```

As an example, I'd like to receive latest records for sensors 1 and 2, not older than 00:00:00. Expected query result has to be:

```
| Date(DateTime)      | SensorId(int) | Value(Double) |
| ------------------- | ------------- | ------------- |
| 2019-10-10T01:11:11 |       1       |       10      |
| 2019-10-10T01:11:11 |       2       |       4       |
```

Here is my query.

```cs
var latestData = await _sharedDbCtx
      .Weather
      .Where(x => postSensors.Contains(x.SensorId) && x.Date >= twoHoursAgo)
      .GroupBy(x => x.SensorId)
      .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Date).First())
      .AsNoTracking()
      .ToListAsync();
```

For some reason, EF does aggregation on client side, but I'd prefer to do it in DBMS because I believe client-side aggregation takes more time. That's what I can see in console:

> warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[20500]
>         The LINQ expression 'GroupBy([airData].SensorId, [airData])' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
>   warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[20500]
>         The LINQ expression 'orderby [y].Date desc' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
>   warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[20500]
>         The LINQ expression 'First()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

Why EF cannot pass aggregation to DBMS?

Comment: Which EF version?

Comment: EF 6.3.0, .NetCore 2.2

Comment: What's `postSensors`? Did you try without that filter? Also, `First` is always tricky on MS SQL, there's no aggregate function for that.

Comment: The error would suggest its some EF Core version and not non-core. There were some issues with local groupings in earlier EF Core that I think were fixed in 3

Comment: `postSensors` is a list of `int` (sensorId's) that I want to work with.

Comment: Try writing your query in sql you will see its not trivial to do what you want the way you want it. You should use aggregate function `Max` on date instead of `Order.First` it might work.